# Quadratic Function Definiton

Tags: functions, quadratics

Can someone give an example of a $3^{rd}$degree polynomial $f_\theta: R^2\rightarrow  R$

Comment: Do you mean "quadratic" or do you mean "3rd degree"?  It can't be both.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. 
That's the reason I have been confused. I want to define the parametric set of the 3rd degree polynomials in a regression model $f_\theta: R^2 \rightarrow  R$

Comment: $f(x,y)=ax^3+bx^2y+cxy^2+dx^3+ex^2+fxy+gy^2+hx+iy+j$ with constants $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j$ with at least one of  $a,b,c$ being non-zero.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thanks for your replay I really appreciate it. So, in $f_\theta: R^2 -> R$ the first term (here R^2) tell us how many variables we will have (here 2 x,y) right? Could you please give another example to understand the concept. For example the $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial  $R^3 -> R$

Comment: Sums of  $$xyz, x^2y, x^2z,, ..., z^3$$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Where can I study about this terminology in order to understand the concept?

Comment: I'm not very good at giving references. Notice that if we add the exponents of $x$ and of $y$ in each term,  it always at most  $3,$ and is $3$ in at least one non-zero  term, which is why it is called a degree-$3$ polynomial in $x,y$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet So, I get why its called $3^{rd}$ degree polynomial, and why  in $f_\theta: R^2 -> R$ the first term $R^2$ tell us how many variables I will have (here 2 so x,y) can you help me to understand what the second term in  $f_\theta: R^2 -> R$ what means?

Comment: I dk what the subscript $\theta$ is referring to . The notation $f:A\to B$ means that $ f$ is a function with domain $A$ and that 
 $f$ maps  $A$ into or onto $B$.... In LaTex:  f:A\to B